# GO - Code stops executing after function return

Tags: go, websocket

So, I'm trying to construct a websocket server in go. And i ran into this interesting bug, which i cant for the life of me figure out why its happening.

**NOTE:** The **comments** in the **code snippets** are there only for this post. **Read them**.

Ive got this function:

```
func Join(ws *websocket.Conn) {
    Log.Connection(ws)

    enc := json.NewEncoder(ws)
    dec := json.NewDecoder(ws)

    var dJ g.DiscussionJoin
    var disc g.Discussion

    Log.Err(dec.Decode(&dJ), "dec.Decode")

    ssD := g.FindDiscussionByID(dJ.DiscussionID)

    ssDJ := dJ.Convert(ws)

    g.DiscHandle <- &ssDJ

    disc = ssD.Convert()

    Log.Err(enc.Encode(disc), "enc.Encode")

    Log.Activity("Discussion", "Joined", disc.DiscussionID.Subject)

    fmt.Println("Listening") //This gets called
    g.Listen(dec)
    fmt.Println("Stoped Listening") //This DOESN'T get called [IT SHOULD]

    ssDJ.SSDiscussion.Leave(ssDJ.SSUserID)

    Log.Disconnection(ws)
}
```

The function thats causing this is (in my opinion) g.Listen(...):

```
func Listen(dec *json.Decoder) {
    timeLastSent := time.Now().Second()
    in := Message{}
    for ((timeLastSent + ConnTimeout) % 60) != time.Now().Second() {
        if err := dec.Decode(&in); err != nil {
            continue
        } else if in == Ping {
            timeLastSent = time.Now().Second()
            continue
        }
        timeLastSent = time.Now().Second()
        Messages <- in
        in = Message{}
    }
    fmt.Println("Client timed out!") //This gets called
    return
}
```

Ive tried both with and without the **return** on the last row of **Listen**

As response to @SimoEndre, Ive left the main method out of the code example, but since you mentioned it, this is the function that takes g.Messege{} out of the Messeges channel.
**NOTE:** MessageHandler() runs on its own go routine.

```
func MessageHandler() {
    for msg := range Messages {
        for _, disc := range LivingDiscussions {
            if disc.DiscussionID.UDID == msg.UDID {
                go disc.Push(msg)
                break
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where does `Messages{}` getting outputted? I don't see it's implemented somewhere

Comment: @SimoEndre how about now? I managed to paste the wrong code snippet.

Comment: look at the tack trace and see where each goroutine is blocked

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the `Listen` function you will remark that it has a `Messages` channel which receive the the `Message{}` struct, but in the main goroutine it does not get outputted. Remember that goroutines are two way communication channels, which means that if a channel does receive an input value it must have an output value the channel to not block.

So you need to create a channel with the same struct type as the `Message{}`

```
message := make(chan Message{})
```

Then in the Join function you have to pop out the value pushed to channel:

```
func Join(ws *websocket.Conn) {
    ...
    <-message
}
```

**Update after new inputs**:

It's not enough to iterate over the values coming from a channel, you need to do this inside a `go func()`.

Getting the values out of different concurrently executing goroutines can be accomplished with the `select` keyword, which closely resembles the switch control statement and is sometimes called the communications switch.

```
go func() {   
    for msg := range Messages {
        for _, disc := range LivingDiscussions {
            if disc.DiscussionID.UDID == msg.UDID {
                select {
                case disc.Push <- msg: // push the channel value to the stack

                default :
                // default action
                }
            }
        }
    }
}()
```

I don't know how your `disc.Push` method is implemented, but if the idea is to push the received channel values to a stack you have to modify your code in a way to send back the channel value to the array. In the code snippet above i've just wanted to emphasize that it's important to get the values back pushed into the channel.

Comment: Thanks for the response,  In order to clarify my question Ive changed the original post slightly.

Comment: I think you missunderstood the entire question, every part of the code works, except the one i mentioned.
eg. both MessageHandler and Push works as intended. & they are both using go routines (as i stated in the post).
The thing is: the channel is NOT the problem here. Ive used it before in another part of the program, and it worked just fine.

Also: if you look at the code provided, the fmt.Println(...) at the end of Listen(...) does get called, BUT the fmt.Println(...) right after the function call to Listen(...) does not. (Ive marked them in the original post)

Comment: @Olian04 - the code doesn't get called after Listen *because Listen blocks*. You need to handle that blocking behavior as per this answer.

Comment: @elithrar how does it get blocked? The second to last row (the fmt.Println(..)) gets called, and that is both outside of the for loop, and its the last call of the function. Whats blocking it?